# Sending data from popup to extension.js not working

Tags: javascript, browser-extension, crossrider

I am working on a browser extension using crossrider. I need to send some data from popup to extension.js

My code of popup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<script type="text/javascript">
/************************************************************************************
  This is your Popup Code. The crossriderMain() code block will be run
  every time the popup is opened.

  For more information, see:
  http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup
*************************************************************************************/

function crossriderMain($) {
  // var to store active tab's URL
  var activeTabUrl = null;

  // Message listener for response from active tab
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'active-tab-url') activeTabUrl = msg.url;
  });

  // Request URL from active tab
  appAPI.message.toActiveTab({type: 'active-tab-url'});

    alert(activeTabUrl);
  // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

Hello World

</body>
</html>
```

Code of Extension.js

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // Message listener
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'active-tab-url')
      // Send active tab's URL to popup
      appAPI.message.toPopup({
        type: 'active-tab-url',
        url:encodeURIComponent(location.href)
      });
  });

  // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
});
```

The value of activeTabUrl is not getting updated. It gives NULL value.
P.S : I am able to communicate between background.js and popup. But for some reason appAPI.message.toActiveTab function is not working for me. Where I am doing the mistake?

Background.js (Edit)

```
var tabUrl='';
 /* appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) {
        tabUrl = tabInfo.tabUrl;
        }); */
 appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
        appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) {
        tabUrl = tabInfo.tabUrl;
        });
       var dataString = '{"url":"'+tabUrl+'","access":"'+msg.access+'","toread":"'+msg.toread+'","comment":"'+msg.comment+'"}';
     alert(dataString);
     appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'REST API URL',
        postData: dataString,
        onSuccess: function(response, additionalInfo) {
            var details = {};
            details.response = response;
            appAPI.message.toPopup({
            response:response
        });

        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        //  alert('POST:: Request failed. HTTP Code: ' + httpCode);
        }
    });
  });
```

Working code of Background.js

```
appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    appAPI.tabs.getActive(function(tabInfo) {     
       var dataString = '{"url":"'+tabInfo.tabUrl+'","access":"'+msg.access+'","toread":"'+msg.toread+'","comment":"'+msg.comment+'"}';
    // alert(dataString);
     appAPI.request.post({
        url: 'http://fostergem.com/api/bookmark',
        postData: dataString,
        onSuccess: function(response, additionalInfo) {
            var details = {};
            details.response = response;
            appAPI.message.toPopup({
            response:response
        });

        },
        onFailure: function(httpCode) {
        //  alert('POST:: Request failed. HTTP Code: ' + httpCode);
        }
    });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code sample, the **activeTabUrl** variable is only set once a response is received from the *extension.js* file since the messaging is asynchronous by design. Hence, when calling `alert(activeTabUrl);` in the code, the message has not yet been received back fro the *extension.js* code thus the value is still null as it was initialized.

To use the **activeTabUrl** variable you must wait for the mesage from the *extension.js* file, and hence you should place the code using the variable in the callback of the message listener, preferably as a function. Also note that using an alert in the popup code causes the popup to close and should hence not be used in the popup scope.

I tested the following popup code, which does away with the variable to avoid confusion and passes the active tab URL as a parameter to the function called in the message listener, and it worked as expected:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
  // Message listener for response from active tab
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'active-tab-url') ShowPageUrl(msg.url);
  });

  function ShowPageUrl(url) {
    $('#page-url').html('<b>Page URL</b>: ' + url);
  }

  // Request URL from active tab
  appAPI.message.toActiveTab({type: 'active-tab-url'});

    //alert(activeTabUrl);
  // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: It worked.But I think there are few bugs as it takes lot of time in sending message from popup and receiving the reply.On some tabs even after waiting for more than 2 minutes , it didn't work. So it can't be used in production. But since I need to post form data along with url to my server, So on form submission I am sending the form data to extension.js and from there I am posting the data to my server. But again it is working for few tabs only. Then I tried to post form data to background.js and from there to my server. But since background.js loads only once so it cant get current tab url.

Comment: In my testing the response time was very fast ... less than a second as should be expected for a small amount of data passing via messaging. Regarding the URL being available in the background scope, you can use [appAPI.tabs.getActive](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-getActive) on browsers on which it is supported, or a messaging technique similar to that mentioned in the answer where the page always sends a message to the background scope with the current URL when it is activated.

Comment: I have used the  appAPI.tabs.getActive. But it is not giving the active tab url. Earlier I thought it gives the url of the tab which is loaded first. But after testing it several times, I found that it is giving the url of previous loaded tab. I have added the code in the question.

Comment: Lets say there are 10 tabs open in the browser. I installed the extension, and submitted the form in extension from crossrider.com. Then I switched to lets say stackoverflow and submitted the form. But still it is giving the url of crossrider.com. Then lets say I moved to another tab(google.com). Now it will give the url of stack overflow. By this pattern, it is actually giving the url of previous tab and not the active tab from where I have submitted the form in extension :(

Comment: Now I have found the problem in my code. When data is posted, the tabUrl is still not updated. But since it is a global variable it still keeps the previous url. I did some modifications in my code and it works perfectly. :)