# Communicating current tab URL to popup

Tags: firefox-addon, crossrider

I've attempted the following code tutorials on StackOverflow, and have not been able to actually receive the active tab URL in the popup.

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043684/sending-data-from-popup-to-extension-js-not-working`

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017681/how-to-send-data-from-popup-script-to-background-js-in-crossrider`

My aim is to receive the active tab URL in the popup, as soon as a user is on that tab. This URL is a reference to data which needs to be obtained from the Database, and hence is essential for my addon.

If a working example could be shown, I would be very grateful.

## EDIT

I can now get the URL in the popup, of a website when the tab is changed or the url is changed. HOWEVER, this isn't useful for me, as I need the URL as soon as the user clicks the popup, so that I can take the URL of the active tab and run queries against the local database for data on it. **How can I do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Post example code of how you are getting the url now. Of your panel widget. Post code, its good for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it in SDK.

But what you want to do is add a TabSelect event listener.

This is how it is done in bootstrap or overlay addons.

```
function exampleTabSelected(event) {
  //tab was selected
  var tab = event.target; //this tab is the actual thingy you click in the tab bar at top
  var tabBrowser = tab.linkedBrowser; //this is the chrome browser within this tab
  var tabContentWindow = tabBrowser.contentWindow; //this is the HTML (or whatever type) contained inside the tab, this is where your website is
  var siteLocationObj = tabContentWindow.location;
  //location now includes properties like href, host, pathname, hash, and port
  //now put your the id of your id of the panel and you can do whatever to it
  var chromeWindow = tab.ownerGlobal; //this is the firefox browser window that the tab is in
  chromeWindow.document.getElementById('YOUR-PANEL-ID-HERE').querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.innerHTML = 'you are now on page: ' siteLocationObj.href;
}

// During initialisation
var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;
container.addEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);

// When no longer needed
//container.removeEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

@infosec In general, in the popup scope you cannot directly determine when a tab becomes active. However, in the background scope you can use the Crossrider [appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-onTabSelectionChanged) method to obtain active tab information and then use [appAPI.message.toPopup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message-method-toPopup) to send the information to the popup.

The code to achieve this would look something like:

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    // Get the Active Tab information
    appAPI.tabs.onTabSelectionChanged(function(tabInfo) {
        // Send it to the popup
        appAPI.tabs.toPopup({tabInfo: tabInfo});
    });
});
```

*crossriderMain* in **popup.html**:

```
function crossriderMain($) {
    appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
        // Do something with the tab URL
        console.log('ActiveTab URL is ' + msg.tabInfo.tabUrl);
    });
}
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]